# Ajax load div in frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a php page that I designed a div to be populated by an Ajax call.

```
function showcopay()
 {

var apa = document.getElementById("alert_id").value;

 $("#copay").load('show_copay.php?pid='+apa);


 }
```

The parent page of the div used to be a popup page. I have moved the page to an iframe. Ajax does not work any more. When I click the link to load the div. Nothing happens.

The content file (show_copay.php) that is being called is in same folder as the parent file as before. Nothing moved as I stated before. I moved the parent page to the iframe and everything stopped working.

Do I need to include a path to the file?

Comment: consult the console, you may have a CORS problem or a url problem

Comment: because some programmers try to reinvent the wheel each time they create a site

Comment: The program was changed (not by me) to improve the UI appearance of the site. So all of the popups were put in iframe pop overs. So now I am having to redo the modification that I made to the program. Not re-inventing the wheel. I looked at the console and it only throws the expected error. Nothing else I can see. I have tried to think of different ways to troubleshot this issue. The CORS is unlikely because as I stated before the two files are locate in the same folder. The content is not coming from a different site.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax was being more precise than imagined in the first place. Because the

```
 doucment.getElementById("alert_id").value
```

was returning a null value (which was shown in the console but I was ignoring it). The console was showing an uncaught exception. So adding the try block around it solved the problem. Now the page works like it use to work.

```
      function showcopay()
       {
        try{
              var apa = document.getElementById("alert_id").value;
           }catch(err){

        }
           $("#copay").load('show_copay.php?pid='+apa);

        }
```